# Spring AOP proxies does not work with JavaFX

Tags: spring, javafx, aop, spring-aop, fxml

Good day, I'm working on a project to use Spring AOP on JavaFX, unfortunately, when I try to wrap an interface which is used in the JavaFX scenes I receive a null pointer. Here is the stack trace.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:303)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl.java:157)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$48/756185697.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafx.scene.Node.getScene(Node.java:907)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$9.invalidated(Scene.java:1074)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.setRoot(Scene.java:1038)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:325)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:181)
    at com.hccs.sample.aspectj.Main.start(Main.java:42)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/50630420.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$44/1051754451.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1570685826.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/1775282465.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1109371569.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application com.hccs.sample.aspectj.Main
```

Here is the Main method, where I create the instance of the MyScene interface and wrap it with proxy.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        Application.launch(Main.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        MyScene scene = context.getBean(MyScene.class);
        if (scene == null) {
            System.out.println("Scene is null on creation");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Scene is not null on creation.");
        }

        // these code are the source of the problem, when these code are
        // commented, it works fine.
        scene = ProxyWrapper.wrap(scene);
        if (scene == null) {
            System.out.println("Scene is null on wrapping");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Scene is not null on wrapping");
        }
        // comment it up to here

        // No problem with manual invocation of methods
        scene.eventOne();
        scene.eventTwo();
        scene.eventThree();

        // Where null pointer occurs
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene((Parent) scene));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Here is the application config.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.hccs.sample.aspectj" })
public class AppConfig {

}
```

Here is the scene interface and implementation which needs to be wrapped.

```
public interface MyScene {
    public void initialize();

    public void eventOne();

    public void eventTwo();

    public void eventThree();

}

@Lazy
@Component
public class MySceneImpl extends BorderPane implements MyScene {

    @FXML
    private Button cmdOne;
    @FXML
    private Button cmdTwo;
    @FXML
    private Button cmdThree;

    public MySceneImpl() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
                    "/com/hccs/sample/aspectj/resources/MyScene.fxml"));
            loader.setRoot(this);
            loader.setController(this);
            loader.load();
            System.out.println("\nKARDS!!\n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    @Override
    public void initialize() {
    }

    @FXML
    @Override
    public void eventOne() {
        System.out.println("One");
    }

    @FXML
    @Override
    public void eventTwo() {
        loopToTen();
    }

    @Override
    public void eventThree() {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                loopToTen();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void loopToTen() {
        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                System.out.println(c + 1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the FXML used in the scene,

```
<fx:root type="BorderPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8">
    <center>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <children>
                <Button fx:id="cmdOne" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#eventOne"
                    text="One" />
                <Button fx:id="cmdTwo" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#eventTwo"
                    text="Two" />
                <Button fx:id="cmdThree" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#eventThree"
                    text="Three" />
            </children>
        </HBox>
    </center>
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
    </padding>
</fx:root>
```

This is the Class that wraps the scene.

```
public class ProxyWrapper {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T wrap(T scene) {
        MyPointcut pointcut = new MyPointcut();
        MyMethodInterceptor aspect = new MyMethodInterceptor();
        Advisor advisor = new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut, aspect);
        ProxyFactory pf = new ProxyFactory();
        pf.setTarget(scene);
        pf.addAdvisor(advisor);
        return (T) pf.getProxy();
    }
}
```

This is the Pointcut and MethodInterceptor classes.

```
public class MyPointcut extends DynamicMethodMatcherPointcut {

    @Override
    public ClassFilter getClassFilter() {
        return new ClassFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean matches(Class<?> clazz) {
                return clazz.getName().contains("MyScene");
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Method method, Class<?> clazz, Object[] key) {
        System.out.println(method.getName() + " == event "
                + method.getName().contains("event"));
        return method.getName().contains("eventT");
    }

}

@Aspect
public class MyMethodInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("START: " + invocation.getMethod().getName());
        Object val = invocation.proceed();
        System.out.println("END: " + invocation.getMethod().getName());
        return val;
    }
}
```

And finally this is the pom.xml of the project.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.hccs.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-aspectj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>sample-aspectj</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

If there's a way for me to make javafx recognize the spring aop proxies, please share it and help me, thanks!

Comment: I am in similar problem but I cannot get it working at all - the FXML Components are always null (I use `spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true` as well). Any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933616/cant-create-aspect-in-spring-boot?noredirect=1#comment78826078_45933616

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't quite figure out exactly why this fails, but making `MySceneImpl` a subclass of `BorderPane` is causing the problem. Basically, the proxy that's created in order to intercept the methods does not initialize the `BorderPane` instance correctly.

The fix is to use aggregation instead of inheritance. Add a method to `MyScene`:

```
public Parent getView() ;
```

and update the implementation class accordingly:

```
@Lazy
@Component
public class MySceneImpl implements MyScene {

    @FXML
    private Button cmdOne;
    @FXML
    private Button cmdTwo;
    @FXML
    private Button cmdThree;

    private final BorderPane view ;

    public MySceneImpl() {

        view = new BorderPane();

        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
                    "/application/MyScene.fxml"));
            loader.setRoot(view);
            loader.setController(this);
            loader.load();
            System.out.println("\nKARDS!!\n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    @Override
    public void initialize() {
    }

    @Override
    public Parent getView() {
        return view ;
    }

    @FXML
    @Override
    public void eventOne() {
        System.out.println("One");
    }

    @FXML
    @Override
    public void eventTwo() {
        loopToTen();
    }

    @Override
    public void eventThree() {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                loopToTen();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void loopToTen() {
        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                System.out.println(c + 1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Here, instead of making `MySceneImpl` a subclass of `BorderPane`, it holds a reference to a `BorderPane` instance. That reference is passed to the `FXMLLoader`'s `setRoot()` method, so it gets populated with the buttons defined in the FXML. Finally, it is returned from the `getView()` method.

Now just update the `Main` class to call `getView()`:

```
// primaryStage.setScene(new Scene((Parent) scene));
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(scene.getView()));
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves exception I've encountered. But the method interceptors are only  being executed when the methods of the MyScene interface are called manually. When the buttons of the javafx stage are called, the method interceptors does not trigger.

Comment: Ah, yes. The issue there is that you are calling `loader.setController(this)`, explicitly passing the `this` reference. Since the constructor that's invoked here is invoked on the target object (i.e. not on the proxy), the controller referenced by the `FXMLLoader` is the target, not the proxy. So the handler methods are not decorated. You're probably going to have to restructure this quite a bit. In particular, the `FXMLLoader` will have to generate the controller from the application context: you can do that with a controller factory, but that factory needs a reference to the app context.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. Be back at you if I got it working, thanks again!

Comment: Another question if you will, in the MySceneImpl class, the buttons are not instantiated when the controllers are wrapped in proxy and the loader.load() is invoked, though the methods are now intercepted. Do you have any idea on solving this problem. Thanks!