# Can't create aspect in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, javafx, spring-aop

I just want to achieve one simple thing - to create logging aspect, which should hook on every method to be able print arguments. The aspect looks like as following:

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class MyLogger {

    public MyLogger () {}

    @AfterReturning("execution(* my.package..*.*(..))")
    public void logMethodAccessAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("***** Completed: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " *****");
    }

    @Before("execution(* my.package..*.*(..))")
    public void logMethodAccessBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("***** Starting: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " *****");
    }

}
```

Thing is, it makes some strange proxy out my beans and the types then do not match. I get following error:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean
>   named 'downloadController' is expected to be of type
>   'my.package.controllers.DownloadController' but was
>   actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60'

Download controller is simple `@Component` which is a JavaFX controller.

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class DownloadController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label speedLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label appNameLabel;

    @FXML
    private ProgressBar downloadProgressBar;

    @FXML
    private Button cancelButton;
```

If I delete the aspect class, everything runs smoothly. Any hint?

**UPDATE**: I am setting up the JavaFX autowiring as following:

```
@Override
public void init() throws Exception {
    SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(XAPStarterApplication.class);
    builder.headless(false);
    springContext = builder.run(XAPStarterApplication.args);
    springContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/MainUI.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
    root = fxmlLoader.load();
}
```

**UPDATE**: I uploaded the sample project in https://github.com/mejmo/aspect-javafx-issue .

Comment: Enable class proxies. Due to the interface you get a dynamic proxy which is an `Initializable` but not a `DownloadController`.

Comment: Do you mean `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` ? No effect. But I deleted the interface `Initializable` and it works. But it would be nice to have it there...

Comment: Only adding that annotation won't do a thing if you don't specify `proxyTargetClass=true` or easier use `spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true` (which should actually be the default).

Comment: Hm nah, it does not work. It starts, but no JavaFX components are autowired in controller. So it must have this `Initializable` interface.

Comment: I added `spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true` to my configuration . The classes implements `Initializable` interface, but JavaFX did not autowire the components.

Comment: If it isn't a spring component no auto wiring will be done. Also not sure if JavaFX can handle proxies correctly.